# Unable to insert multiple filename in database

Tags: php

```js
<input type="file" name="doc[]" class="form-control"/>
<input type="file" name="doc[]" class="form-control"/>
<input type="file" name="doc[]" class="form-control"/>
<input type="file" name="doc[]" class="form-control"/>
```

```html
<?php
foreach($_FILES['linkdocs']['name'] as $key=>$val){ 
$linkdocs=basename($_FILES['linkdocs']['name'][$key]); }
?>
```

$sqlitem_data="INSERT INTO `data` (`tid`,`doc`) VALUES (NULL,'$linkdocs')";

i am using the following code but this code is only inserting only one file from all selected file
pls help!
i want all the files should be in one column of the table like  "file1 , file2 , file3 , file4"

Comment: Where is `$doc` coming from, in your code above? I take it that extra line should be inside the loop? Slightly o/t, but if the `tid` column doesn't need a value, just set a default and leave it out of the query.

Comment: @droopsnoot Thanks, pls check my updated code! ok but i am asking for "How i can insert multiple filename like file1 , file2 " if i am using the above code this only insert one filename instead

Comment: Your insert appears to occur after the loop ends. Therefore it will only have access to the last value that $linkdocs was set to. The insert needs to happen inside the loop. This is a basic logic error.

Comment: @ADyson but actually I have other input fields as well so this will not work.

Comment: If your form has `input type="file" name="doc[]"`, why is your code trying to look at `$_FILES['linkdocs']` - is there a step somewhere that renames it? What is actually in `$_FILES` when your form submits?

Comment: As @ADyson said, you'll have to insert the docs inside a loop. If you don't, you either only get the last value of `$linkdocs`, or you have to bodge it by concatenating multiple names into a single column in your table, which you really don't want to do.

Comment: `I have other input fields as well so this will not work `...this doesn't seem to make sense. If you are uploading multiple documents for one set of other fields, and you only want to insert those other fields once, then presumably you should insert the fields into the main table, get the inserted IDs, and then insert multiple records (one per document) into a secondary table, using the ID from the first table as a foreign key to link the records.

Comment: P.s. `i want all the files should be in one column of the table like "file1 , file2 , file3 , file4`... **no, you don't** . This is a terrible design flaw which will make your database stink. It will be harder to query and retrieve data, harder to delete or update individual items within it, harder to filter etc. It breaks a fundamental rule of relational database design. You need a second table with a foreign key back to the main one, as I described just above. If you don't understand this, please spend some time learning about database normalisation and one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @Adyson I got your point but the thing is we have thousands of data to be inserted for a particular Id and I don't need filter and requires removal of particular item.

Comment: Not right now you don't, perhaps, but don't assume you won't have such requirements in the future. Things always change. People always ask for features they said they didn't want initially. Designing it properly shouldn't be a problem, and it isn't difficult. There shouldn't be any reason to avoid doing that . Do it properly from the beginning and then you don't need to worry about future changes.

Comment: ok thanks i will take care of it!